# Difference between " readyState === 'Interactive' " and " Jquery.ready() "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Today I am Playing with `DOM readyState`,And I find something strange in `JQuery.ready()`,

`JQuery.ready()` event occurs before `DOMContentload` event then i put `interactive` in my code

like : `document.readyState ===  "interactive"`

Then this code is load before `Jquery.ready()` So, I have a question , is

`JQuery.ready()` is equal or similar to `document.readyState ===  "interactive`?
and What Technique JQuery Applies in there .ready() Event ?
How I apply this `.ready()` in my pure Javascript ?

I read lots of similar post of that type but no one gives the exact solution to implement   `JQuery.ready()` on JavaScript they all load after `DOMContentload` not when `.ready()`.

[**Here MY Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/mg3tF/)

Comment: jquery ready uses DOMContentLoaded event in browsers that support it. In ones that don't support it, window load is used.

Comment: jquery ready is a pseudo event using a promise, there is no in-build equivalent event in native javascript

Comment: Please check my fiddle why `jquery.ready()` occurs first then `DOMContentLoaded` if it uses Same ?

Comment: How i create this Event in my pure JS @A. Wolff

Comment: Hmmm I thought jquery source code is available! :)

Comment: @AshishMishra Well, one of them has to happen first, they can't happen at the same time. jQuery bound it's event before you bound yours, so the jquery one happened first.

Comment: Ya you right,but, Whenever i execute the code,Only `Jquery.ready()` always happen first...and what is for `interactive`

Comment: You are right @Adriano ! but My question is why Jquery.ready() occurs first?

Comment: @AshishMishra i'd expect ready handler to be called after DOMContentLoaded , not before. Now, I don't know what happen. I've checked jQuery source but cannot find any explication of this behaviour. EDIT: Ok, i think it is because jQuery bind its own DOMContentLoaded  before you bind your own DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Ya ,that's why i post this question,, I also doesn't understand why this happens ?@A. Wolff

Comment: @AshishMishra see following my previous EDIT comment, that's it: http://jsfiddle.net/mg3tF/2/

Comment: Right, it's first in first out. and jQuery's will always be first in, unless you run your code before you include jquery.

Comment: Thanks to solve my confusion ...but please tell me about interactive and please post it as answer ..@A. Wolff

Answer (score 1):

when we browse something the `document.readyState` can be one of the following:

```
loading
```

The document is still loading.

```
interactive
```

The document has finished loading and the document has been parsed but sub-resources such as images, stylesheets, and frames are still loading.

```
complete
```

The document and all sub-resources have finished loading. The state indicates that the `load` event is about to fire.

`JQuery.ready()` is not equal or similar to `document.readyState ===  "interactive` because `.redyState` return a string  `interactive` or `loading` browser is syncing data from server, when it done it return `complete` string  and create a `load` event.

The jQuery uses the above functionality to create the `doc.ready()` for their library.

1. if you wish to run your function after loading the document, there are many ways... but one of these

```js
function myFun(){
  // All your JS code which will use in your document
  console.log("Hey now I am ready to run");
}
// just call the myFun() in a eventListene function as callback function
//the myFun will run after the 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFun, false);
```

2. A little idea what jQuery does (which will work wherever the script tag is placed).

```js
const ready =(fun) => {
   if(document.ready == 'interactive' || document.readyState =="complete"){
      // calling function
      setTimeout(fun, 1);
          }
          // we can also implement by event listner
          else {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fun);
          }
        }
ready(() =>  {
          // This is the functin whitch pass to the ready function
          console.log("I am ready.")
        });
```

hey I know that is not good but the idea behind it is that.

3. A little idea what jQuery does (which will work wherever the script tag is placed).
   The alternative ways are
   if supported, it tries the standard:

window.addEventListener('load', fn, false )

with a fallback to:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
```

with a fallback to:

```
window.addEventListener('load', fn, false )
```

or for older versions of IE, it uses:

```
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", fn);



window.attachEvent("onload", fn);
```

the information taken from :[document.ready on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)